# Cordova app - client side logging and monitoring

Tags: cordova, monitoring, client-side, error-logging

I am running a cordova app on IOS and Android platforms. I want to log client-side logs and also want to monitor application (user behaviour, errors etc). At the moment, its sort of not visible to me. It would be good if i can monitor page views, major button clicks and if they received an unhandled error.

-Are there any tools that you can recommend?
-What is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: As for the internal app errors, the Google Play Developer Console is all you need. You can track errors from there and get detailed descriptions of (Java) errors, which are the more serious ones.

Comment: did you use appsee? any feedback on that?